# TS will not infer possible undefined when destructuring empty array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, destructuring, type-safety

When looking at the inferred type of destructured element, it will assume the array is never empty.

```
const x: number[] = [];
const [first] = x; // first inferred as number

console.log(first); // undefined

if (first !== undefined) {
    // ...
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhmArgWwEYFMBOBtAXRgF4ZCBuAKFEljwDMBLHaI0ucmAei5iZdiMw9XDiwATGAEMIydNhyVq4CCAA2WAHRqQAcwAU-aAEpOPGCjDisTMBKWN6MQ82gwAhMVKXrticZgAb0oYUO5eTUjKAF9KIA)

This leads to an interesting behavior with TSLint rule "strict-type-predicates" for example, that will mark the if statement as always true, while it's in fact isn't.

Am I missing something and it's normal behavior?

Comment: https://github.com/danielnixon/eslint-plugin-total-functions#total-functionsno-unsafe-destructuring

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### UPDATE for TypeScript 4.1

It is still the intended behavior that `undefined` is not included in the domain of index signature properties, for the reasons listed below.  However, since this is an oft-requested feature, the TypeScript team has (somewhat grudgingly?) relented and added the [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess).  If you enable that (and it is neither enabled by default, nor included in the `--strict` compiler flag, so you need to do it explicitly), you will start getting the behavior you presumably want.

Note that this is actually not exactly the same as adding `undefined` yourself.  Indexed access will add `undefined`:

```
// --noUncheckedIndexedAccess is enabled

const x: number[] = [];
const [first] = x; // number | undefined

console.log(first); // undefined

if (first !== undefined) {
    first.toFixed(); // okay
}
```

But `for..of` loops and array functional programming methods will still act as though `undefined` is not possible (that is: as if sparse arrays do not exist):

```
for (const n of x) {
    n.toFixed(); // no error, yay!
}

x.map(n => n.toFixed()); // no error, yay!
```

So possibly you want to enable that flag.  Keep in mind that some common array/dictionary manipulation techniques may still be "annoying", which is why it isn't part of the `--strict` family.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgCjAVwLYCMCmAnASgG0BdGAXhlIG4AoUSWIgMwEs9ozK5qYB6PjHTZ8MAD4w0YACY42YHNNr1wEEABscAOnUgA5sjYcoBXgMky5rBUtqtmKI9BgBCcpSmz5igjADetDBBME5QWlAgAGKscIrIpvyCIADWAIYAnrQAvsrMIHgoDM5gMCAOcL4BwULhUTFxCeZgIDD4ePkANDDpGS7ZynBaGKkADqgUAHw1EdGx0vGNgs2teO14XT3pfUA)

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

It's the intended behavior. See [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778) for more information.  This issue is a request to allow index signature property types to automatically include `undefined` in their domain, and while the issue is still open, it is fairly clear that it will not be implemented.  See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-286592106) for example.

It is [not a design goal of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) (see #3 on the list) for the type system to be perfectly sound or correct (despite the heartache that people like me feel when we think about this too much; I've joked before about starting a TypeScript Unsoundness Support Group to help people deal with this).  Instead, there's a tradeoff between correctness and usability.

The language maintainers note that there's a lot of real-world code out there which indexes into arrays without checking for possible `undefined` values everywhere, and that enforcing this check would turn a simple for-loop into a tedious exercise of either performing checks or using type assertions.  The problem is (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-286859503)) that the compiler cannot easily tell the difference between safe and unsafe indexes into array types.  So either the compiler assume that the property won't be `undefined` and have false negatives from the compiler when that assumption is wrong, as happens now.... *or*, assume the property might be `undefined` and have false positives from the compiler when the indexing operation is actually safe.  The argument by the language maintainers is that such false positives would happen so often that developers would condition themselves to ignore the errors entirely, thus making it just as useless as the current situation while being more annoying.  So they will leave it as it is now.

---

If you want, you can always add `undefined` to the element type yourself, assuming such issues are more likely to show up for you in your use cases:

```
const x: (number | undefined)[] = [];
const [first] = x; // number | undefined

console.log(first); // undefined

if (first !== undefined) {
    first.toFixed(); // okay
}
```

but keep in mind that you'll run into the annoying situation if your use cases follow the normal patterns:

```
for (const n of x) {
    n.toFixed(); // error, annoying
    if (typeof n !== "undefined") n.toFixed(); // okay
    n!.toFixed(); // okay
}

x.map(n => n.toFixed()); // error, annoying
x.filter((n): n is number => typeof n !== "undefined").filter(n => n.toFixed()); // okay
x.map(n => n!.toFixed()); // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgCjAVwLYCMCmAnGAHxjTABMcAzASzBzIEoBtAXRgF4ZWBuAKFEiwmNPNDac43GAHppMdNnxES5KrXq9+4CCAA2OAHS6QAc2QjoDKbJUUadMrxi9qlFBdgBCdp1J31jDAA3k4wYR4GUCAAYtRw9MhWMnIgANYAhgCevAC+mryUIATIAtDyMCBucAzBoWFgkTFxCUk2+HhFADQw6WBgIJm0JnUwrihQmQAOOJXl3pwARH5qDgs1DVGx8WSJ1ikZ2WH1no1bLXsVB7macAYY6ZOoHAB88qfNOwytcu1dPX0DIa8W40XRQfDIVAMJBgUYQeSYXAEdivCbTWaw+YwJaqez0NYGUHgvBPFFvTYfRLfS5ZYF3B6k15gE4U7ZUi5pLJAA)

Comment: This clears the topic completely, thank you for the detailed response!

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-691331991 it's implemented recently

Comment: @YLJ yes, thanks.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys! I've been banging my head on it for days!